# Deserialization of xml to list of object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Im having a problem deserializing my xml file to a list of objects.
The error that appears is "System.InvalidOperationException: "There is an error in XML document (2,2). InvalidOperationException `<Feed xmlns=">` was not expected.
There seems to be something wrong when the conversion of xml to objects take place.

The program seems to break at: `list = (List<object>) loadXML.Deserialize(fs);`

```
public static List<object> deSerialize()
        {

            string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\xmlfile.xml";
            XmlSerializer loadXML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<object>));

            List<object> list = new List<object>();
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    list = (List<object>) loadXML.Deserialize(fs);

                    //var lista = (List<object>)obj;

                    return list;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
        }
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Feed xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>NASA Breaking News</Name>
  <NumberOfEpisodes>10</NumberOfEpisodes>
  <Episodes>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASA Invites Media to Next SpaceX Space Station Cargo Launch</Title>
      <Description>Media accreditation is open for the launch of the next SpaceX delivery of science investigations, supplies, and equipment to the International Space Station.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>2</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASA Administrator Invites Public to Update on Agencyâ€™s Return to Moon</Title>
      <Description>The public is invited to join NASA Administrator Jim Bridenstine at 9:40 a.m. EDT Friday, Oct. 25, for an update on the agencyâ€™s Artemis program and the critical role international partnerships have in returning astronauts to the Moon and going on to Mars.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>3</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>Maryland, Washington Students to Speak with NASA Astronaut Aboard Space Station</Title>
      <Description>Students from Maryland and Washington, D.C., will have an opportunity this week to talk with a NASA astronaut currently living and working aboard the International Space Station.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>4</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASA Invites Media to Boeing Starliner Transport to Launch Site</Title>
      <Description>Media accreditation is open for two-days of activities in mid-November for the next milestone in NASAâ€™s Commercial Crew Program, as Boeingâ€™s CST-100 Starliner is transported for integration on a United Launch Alliance (ULA) Atlas V rocket.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>5</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASA to Provide Coverage of Key Events at 70th International Astronautical Congress</Title>
      <Description>NASA will provide live coverage on NASA Television of key events at the 70th International Astronautical Congress (IAC), which takes place Oct. 21-25 at the Walter E. Washington Convention Center in Washington.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>6</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>In-Space News Conference to Review First All-Woman Spacewalk</Title>
      <Description>NASA astronauts Christina Koch and Jessica Meir will participate in a news conference from orbit at noon EDT, Monday, Oct. 21, following their Friday spacewalk â€“ the first to be conducted by two women.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>7</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASAâ€™s Planetary Protection Review Addresses Changing Reality of Space Exploration</Title>
      <Description>NASA released a report Friday with recommendations from the Planetary Protection Independent Review Board (PPIRB) the agency established in response to a recent National Academies of Sciences, Engineering, and Medicine report and a recommendation from the NASA Advisory Council.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>8</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASA to Televise First All-Female Spacewalk, Host Media Teleconference</Title>
      <Description>On the first ever all-female spacewalk, NASA astronauts Christina Koch and Jessica Meir will venture outside the International Space Station about 7:50 a.m. EDT Friday, Oct. 18, to replace faulty equipment on the stationâ€™s exterior. Live coverage will begin at 6:30 a.m. on NASA Television and the agencyâ€™s website.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>9</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASA Invites Media to Launch of Solar Orbiter Spacecraft</Title>
      <Description>NASA has opened media accreditation for the Feb. 5, 2020, launch of Solar Orbiter â€“ a joint NASA/ESA (European Space Agency) mission that will address central questions concerning our star, the Sun.</Description>
    </Episode>
    <Episode>
      <EpisodeNumber>10</EpisodeNumber>
      <Title>NASA to Discuss Planetary Protection Reviewâ€™s Findings and Recommendations</Title>
      <Description>NASA will host a media teleconference at 3:30 p.m. EDT Friday, Oct. 18, to discuss recommendations presented by the Planetary Protection Independent Review Board (PPIRB), established in June 2019 by Thomas Zurbuchen, associate administrator for the agencyâ€™s Science Mission Directorate.</Description>
    </Episode>
  </Episodes>
</Feed>
```

Comment: You need to define suitable `Feed` and `Episode` classes, and then `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Feed))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by defining types which model your XML. I generated these by copying your XML and then going to Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes in Visual Studio (and tidying up the results by hand), but you can also write them by hand (using [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization) and specifically [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes) as reference) or use [`xsd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe).

```
public class Feed
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte NumberOfEpisodes { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("Episode")]
    public List<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}

public class Episode
{
    public byte EpisodeNumber { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Feed));
var feed = (Feed)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define type of the object that System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer can serialize.
Example:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
return (MyType)xs.Deserialize(new StringReader(myXmlString));
```